# Use Certificate on WCF service that hosted inside Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

How can I host a WCF service inside a Widows Service, which uses HTTPS connection using a self signed certificate generated by makecert tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guy's post is pretty thorough.  I have used it myself successfully.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/james_osbornes_blog/archive/2010/12/10/selfhosting-a-wcf-service-over-https.aspx